# Did Garou surpass Boros' power by chapter 165?

Tags: one-punch-man

As far as I remember, Boros's most powerful attack was an energy beam that when deflected caused an Earth wide wave over the entire ocean. However, Garou's attack in chapter 165,

> it caused the entire Earth to bend

That has to be more powerful than Boros' last attack right? Or was there another attack from Boros which was more powerful?

Did Garou surpass Boros' power by chapter 165?